# Exponent for certain part of the data

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to exponent a certain part of the data set here.

I have a table like this:
Called DF

| Participant | Date | XPL | WAYS | SPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location | TBD | 12 | 3 | 5.5 |
| George | 10_Sep_Mon | 23 | 12 | 12.7 |
| Sam | 10_Sep_Mon | 14 | 2.5 | 5 |
| Carl | 10_Sep_Mon | 21 | 2.8 | 5.1 |

I only want to apply an operation on the second row, starting on George, and just the section between XPL, WAYS and SPM. I do not want to do any calculation on the first row.

| Participant | Date | XPL | WAYS | SPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location | TBD | 12 | 3 | 5.5 |
| George | 10_Sep_Mon | **23** | **12** | **12.7** |
| Sam | 10_Sep_Mon | **14** | **2.5** | **5** |
| Carl | 10_Sep_Mon | **21** | **2.8** | **5.1** |

The end result, I want to put that number to the power of 3, so for example, 3^23 for George at XPL. What is the best way to do this for a large data set where it would be hard to "hard code" it?

| Participant | Date | XPL | WAYS | SPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location | TBD | 12 | 3 | 5.5 |
| George | 10_Sep_Mon | 3^23 | 3^12 | 3^12.7 |
| Sam | 10_Sep_Mon | 3^14 | 3^2.5 | 3^5 |
| Carl | 10_Sep_Mon | 3^21 | 3^2.8 | 3^5.1 |

So ideally, I would have the numerical value for the section applied. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
Participant <- c("Location", "George", "Sam", "Carl")
Date <- c("TBD", "10_Sep_Mon", "10_Sep_Mon", "10_Sep_Mon")
XPL <- c(12, 23, 14, 21)
WAYS <- c(3, 12, 2.5, 2.8)
SPM <- c(5.5, 12.7, 5, 5.1)
DF <- data.frame(Participant, Date, XPL, WAYS, SPM)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr) 

DF %>% mutate(across(XPL:SPM, ~ c(.x[1], 3^.x[-1])))
#>   Participant       Date         XPL         WAYS          SPM
#> 1    Location        TBD          12      3.00000       5.5000
#> 2      George 10_Sep_Mon 94143178827 531441.00000 1146673.9198
#> 3         Sam 10_Sep_Mon     4782969     15.58846     243.0000
#> 4        Carl 10_Sep_Mon 10460353203     21.67402     271.2179
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`

```
DF[-1, 3:5] <- 3^DF[-1, 3:5]
```

-output

```
> DF
  Participant       Date         XPL         WAYS          SPM
1    Location        TBD          12      3.00000       5.5000
2      George 10_Sep_Mon 94143178827 531441.00000 1146673.9198
3         Sam 10_Sep_Mon     4782969     15.58846     243.0000
4        Carl 10_Sep_Mon 10460353203     21.67402     271.2179
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! If those number values were characters, and not numerical, what would be the best way to address that issue if it arises?

Comment: @dkcongo Not clear from your question.  If you have columns that are supposed to be numeric, but for some reason as character class.  You could change the type with `DF <- type.convert(DF, as.is = TRUE)`.  and then use the `DF`.  If that doesn't solve, i.e. it is possible to have a single character in a column that makes it character class.  In that case, you may need to force convert column with `as.numeric` i..e. `DF[3:5] <- lapply(DF[3:5], as.numeric)` assuming `character` class